# Deployment Error: Property 'activateRSS' not valid in version 28.0

Tags: deployment, ant, remote-site-settings, properties

I am using ANT to deploy a custom package which includes custom code and managed packages. I have deployed the custom package to multiple environments without any issues but I am now facing the following error when attempting to deploy to higher environments.

> Property 'activateRSS' not valid in version 28.0

I am the owner of the managed packages and have done a search to see if I can find where the `activateRSS` property is being referenced and it is not in any file of either managed packages. I also have access to the custom source code, and a search for `activateRSS` also returned 0 results.

Does anybody know why I may be receiving such error and how I should go about resolving it?

**Update (July 19th)**

New Known Issue : [Metadata deploy of InstalledPackage in v42 and below failing when activateRSS is not specified.](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=metadata-deploy-of-installedpackage-in-v42-and-below-failing-when-activaterss-is-not-specified&Id=a1p3A000000Fmbh)

Comment: I get this too. Is there a fix yet? this is stopping me deploy to our customers staging org

Comment: @MarcusMaximi have you wrote your own ANT tasks that may be performing the package retrieval at time of package installation? Or how are you retrieving the package to be installed/upgraded?

Answer (score 3):

There is the Known Issue - [Summer'18 - unrecognized field activateRSS on InstalledPackage while using MetaData API](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000FmKqQAK), which indicates it should have been resolved in *SUMMER '18 PATCH 10.1* and is currently deployed to all pods.

It does provide some clues as to where the `activateRSS` element appears under `InstalledPackage`.

[`InstalledPackage.activateRss`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_installedpackage.htm) is only valid from API versions 43.0 and later. So it could certainly cause problems with an older 28.0 version of the MetadataAPI via the ANT deploy tool.

I'd double check any metadata you have for InstalledPackage elements.

Comment: This is still failing for us. Any news about it?

Comment: @jvrdelafuente Is your failure directly related to the existing known issue, or is it a variation of an activateRSS error?

Comment: Salesforce are looking into this issue through a support case for me. They have mentioned that the known issue indicated in @DanielBallinger answer may have resurfaced.

Comment: I think that is the same issue. `installedPackages/projectName.installedPackage -- Error: Property 'activateRSS' not valid in version 36.0`. It looked like it was fixed on Friday but it broke again during the weekend.

Comment: There was a Salesforce patch rolled back over very recently. That might explain why it has regressed.

Comment: Is there any new about this? We are still having the issue and that's preventing us to release

Comment: just a comment from me that in my case it was failing in Salesforce DX instead of ant. Changing `sourceApiVersion` in `sfdx-project.json` to 43 did the work

Answer (score 3):

Using `<activateRSS>true</activateRSS>` solve the issue.
Though `<activateRSS xsi:nil="true"/>` this was giving error.

So
Ideal package.xml would look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InstalledPackage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <activateRSS>true</activateRSS>
    <versionNumber>xyz</versionNumber>
</InstalledPackage>
```